# Unable to install geopandas using Anaconda -- UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other

Tags: anaconda, geopandas

I recently wiped my computer. I reinstalled Anaconda Navigator and am now able to open Jupyter Notebook but cannot install geopandas as I get an error that reads:

> No packages will be modified.
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
>
> Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following
> specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
>
> - feature:/osx-64::__osx==10.16=0
> - geopandas -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.2.0'] -> __osx[version='>=10.11']
>
> Your installed version is: 10.16

I also tried:

```
conda install geopandas
```

and

```
pip install geopandas
```

in the terminal but neither of those worked either.

Note I am in Mac OS Monterey version 12.6.6

EDIT:

I tried again in the terminal and got the following:

> Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve.
> Retrying with flexible solve. Solving environment: unsuccessful
> attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next
> repodata source.
>
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment:
> unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with
> flexible solve. Solving environment: \
>
> Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. This can take
> several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort. failed
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
> incompatible with each other:
>
> Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following
> specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
>
> - feature:/osx-64::__osx==10.16=0
> - geopandas -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.2.0'] -> __osx[version='>=10.11']

which is basically the same but with more details.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try this in a fresh environment? Did you install *everything* in that environment from the conda-forge channel?

Answer (score 0):

Installing from conda-forge should do the trick.

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

Also, it's a good idea to work in a virtual environment to have more control over which packages (and versions) are installed.